# gobject name error even though there is no import error

Tags: gtk, pygobject, gobject, appindicator

So,I am making a pygtk appindicator and requires a certain function to be called regularly.
gobject.timeout_add(millisec,function) is one solution to this.

I have imported all gi modules in this way:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')

from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
from gi.repository import Notify as notify
```

and there has been no import error whatsoever.
Then, in my main function I call :

```
gobject.timeout_add(2000,pr)
```

This is the actual code snippet:

```
def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, os.path.abspath('spotify.svg'),   appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu())
    notify.init(APPINDICATOR_ID)
    gobject.timeout_add(2000,pr) 
    gtk.main()
```

and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "appin.py", line 128, in <module>
    gobject.timeout_add(2000,pr) 
NameError: name 'gobject' is not defined
```

Even if I replace gobject with GObject I get the same error.

So,please help me to resolve the same.
Thank You  in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `as gobject` in your import statement. You remembered it for the other libraries at least. Remember that Python is case-sensitive; `GObject` and `gobject` are different.